# How to deal with "method not found in class" warning for magically implemented methods?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am sitting on a large codebase that contains several classes that expose functionality through magically implemented methods (using `__call` and `__callStatic`). For example:

```
class Foo {
    public function __call($name, $parameters) {
        echo "You called $name().\n";
    }
}

$f = new Foo;
$f->test();   // runs fine, but PhpStorm flags as a warning
```

The problem is that PhpStorm thinks that the `test()` method does not exist, so it gives a warning at the call site. This is a little annoying, as of course the code will run and behave as expected.

I have already tuned down the severity by checking the "downgrade severity if __magic methods are present in class" option, but I would prefer to either:

1. completely disable this functionality for specific classes *only*, or
2. work with the IDE rather than against it -- provide it with the information I already have so our views agree

**Is any of the above possible? If so, how?**

Additional bonus question: consider the case where method calls are being chained.

```
$f = new Foo;
$f->test()->chain()->moreChain();   // potentially runs fine
```

Assuming that the magic call to `$f->test()` returns something appropriate the subsequent (possibly, but not necessarily, also magic) calls will work fine. However, since there is no way that I know of to tell the IDE what `test()` returns it flags the rest of the call chain as full of missing methods too. And to make matters worse, the "downgrade severity" setting does not apply to these warnings since the IDE does not know what class these intermediate objects are supposed to be.

**Is there a solution that can also cover this case?**

### Update

Even though documenting the magic methods with `@method` annotations seems to work, I have to assume that there are currently several problems with this approach because it only took me a little work to come upon these related bugs:

- [Type hinting for the method arguments does not work correctly with primitives](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13654)
- [Annotations work for one call, but not for chained calls](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13731)

I do hope they fix them in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: Perhaps adding a docblock for every method could work?

Comment: @JvdBerg: Add a docblock where? (How) Will the IDE know to associate these docblocks with nonexistent methods?

Comment: @JvdBerg: For every method possible? Not sure if trolling or serious...

Comment: There was a long discussion at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1711 which lead to the severity downgrade option. It looks like there is no other way to do it, though it was suggested to add class level suppress annotation or read phpdoc `@method` annotations. Also I don't recommend adding new tags for every product version, this will confuse users and those who watch for tags will not be able to track questions tagged with the new tags.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Well, theoretically there could be an infinite number of methods that `__call` implements (that's the whole point, to do it dynamically). *Practically* the number will be much more manageable (somewhere between 5 and 50).

Comment: @CrazyCoder: I think it's a good idea to use version-specific tags because people *have* to get this information from *somewhere* -- tags seems most appropriate. I did tag with plain `phpstorm` on purpose so that watchers can also track this.

Comment: @Jon: version information is not always needed to answer the question. When it's needed, it can be asked in comments. Otherwise there would be dozens of tags with new tags appearing after every version, tracking it would be a mess as some users may use only new, version specific tags.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: New tags appearing every year does not sound like a big mess. In any case I was guided by the `visual-studio` tag situation. Is there a discussion somewhere on meta about this?

Comment: @Jon, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744: **In general, you should strongly avoid creating version tags**.

Comment: If you want code completion and other analysis working on such dynamic methods, then using `@method` is the only choice right now (and only real/correct choice in my opinion) as it describes one method at a time with **full** details (method name, parameter names/order and param types, return type).

Comment: I agree with @LazyOne, `@method` works fine on class level.

Comment: @LazyOne et al: I'm pretty late to the game. But are you guys saying PHPStorm does autocomplete, or at least not give false positive warnings, if a virtual method is documented with `@method`? It's not the case for me, so I'm wondering if I've got to configure this or have muddled up the format somehow.

Comment: @faintsignal `@method` works, lots of stuff uses it. It's for class methods. For "virtual" properties `@property` tag exists. Without seeing a code sample -- hard to say what might be wrong there.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the confirmation. This never worked for me in Eclipse so I assumed that was the case for PHPStorm as well when I saw the inspection warnings. Turns out the docblock was missing an asterisk--I've adjusted colour coding so I'll recognize the problem right away in the future.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, you can go to the preference menu, under *Inspections*, go to *Undefined -> Undefined Method* and check **Downgrade severity if __magic methods are present**.

That would make the flag less severe, (instead of Warning, as Info), which would still give you a green light on your document check.

There's nothing else I'm aware of aside from having `@property` or `@method` PHPDoc notations on the target class for every method that's likely to be used.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to find the right inspection to disable under the settings window. But there's another way: put the cursor on any annoying error then press `Alt`+`Enter` and look for "Disable Inspection"

Comment: There is a quick way to bring up the Preferences --> Editor --> inspections screen similar to image above.  Place your cursor over the method, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select Add Method --> Edit Inspection Profile Setting.  This will open a screen similar to the image above with the Undefined method already highlighted.

Answer (score 40):

Rather than globally turning off inspections by downgrading the severity of the inspection, you can add a comment to the single line to ignore just that particular inspection.

```
    /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */
    Assertion::NullOrAssertionDoesNotExist();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is "for specific classes only" as the OP wants

Comment: You have to put it before every occurrence.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/suppressing-inspections.html may be of use if you need more information about this. I'm not sure where to change the version.

Comment: This option seems odd. Why should you pollute your project with this kind of phpdoc when this is only for disabeling inspection in phpStorm. Let's say you collegue uses *cough* Aptana the comments dont even make sense to them. Best way to get rid of these `'magic fields'` is to add phpdoc and a property definition for them

Comment: My example was to suppress PHPStorm notification in a unit test which was purposefully testing the behaviour of making a call to something that doesn't exist. So, adding a docblock to say that something exists would be wrong.

As I'm not the author of PHPStorm, I can only suggest what is a working solution. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Disabling such inspection globally should be really avoided, and adding the @method tags is not always faisable, mostly when working with vendor libraries (think of composer).

Answer (score 3):

Building on what Madara said, I found it wouldn't downgrade down far enough for my liking no matter what severity I set it to, so I made a new Severity for undefined method that has *no attributes whatsoever*, and turned off the downgrade checkbox (see image below)

[image]

If I hover over my magic methods now, it still brings up the popup message, but otherwise it doesn't distract me. One step better than just turning off inspection, because at least this way an actual undefined method can still be detected by hovering over the name

Comment: This also won't work. You would need to uncheck 'downgrade severity' to enable this severity to be used and then you'd be hiding all undefined methods everywhere this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic variable :

```
$test = 'test';
$chaine = $f->$test();   // no phpStorm flag, & the code works
```

Comment: You also can `$f->__call('test')`. But is it worthy?

Comment: You can also use `$chain = $f->{'test'}();` to save a line :)