# Phpstorm code completion not working on php methods

Tags: php, phpstorm

For some reason code completion is worry on native php code such as bind_param(), prepare() and execute(). I get this warning: method 'bind_param' not found in class. What is the problem?

```
if ($this->comparePassword ( $password, $confirmPass )) {

            // Generating password hash
            $password_hash = PassHash::hash ( $password );

            // insert query
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare ( "INSERT INTO seeker(first_name, last_name, email, password, parish) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" );
            $stmt->bind_param ( "sssss", $fName, $lName, $email, $password_hash, $parish );

            $result = $stmt->execute ();

            $stmt->close ();

            // Check for successful insertion
            if ($result) {
                // User successfully inserted
                return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            } else {
                // Failed to create user
                return USER_CREATE_FAILED;
            }
        } else {
            return PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH;
        }
    } else {
        // User with same email already existed in the db
        return USER_ALREADY_EXISTED;
    }
```

Here is the code for the custom class

```
class DbConnect {

private $conn;

function __construct() {        
}

/**
 * Establishing database connection
 * @return database connection handler
 */
function connect() {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); //EDIT TO BE PDO

    // Check for database connection error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { //EDIT TO BE PDO
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); //EDIT TO BE PDO
    }

    // returning connection resource
    return $this->conn;
}
```

}

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12583095/

Comment: the code works fine but for some reason the code completion not working. it works with everything thing else such as with zend, sublime etc.

Comment: Did you see the link I gave you above?

Comment: is not it suppose to pick up the native php methods from the interpreter?

Comment: read it already that only tell the editor to not show it as a warning. It does not make the auto-complete work for php methods

Comment: Is `$this->conn` an instance of `\mysqli` or a custom database class?

Comment: What version of phpstorm are you running?

Comment: You need doccomments before the variable declarations to tell PhpStorm what the class of the variables are, so it knows what methods apply to it.

Comment: If it's of any relance, PhpStorm 8 B138.1901 Sep 2, 2014 - *"PHP Completion:
WI-16026 (Bug): Trait: Autocompletion doesn't recognize protected methods"*. I don't know phpstorm, but that's what I found.

Comment: it is an instance of mysqli but it is in a custom class. ill post the code above.

Comment: the version is 8.0.1

Comment: could you give me an example of what i would need to do with this doccomments things to get it to work? @barmar

Comment: it works now. thanks guys. Apparently i needed to do the - @return mysqli thing in my db class

Comment: @CastellJames I suggest you post your own answer with the solution. The comment about that, seems to have been deleted. I think your question a good addition to Stack, and others could profit from it. Please post it as an answer. Stack will let you accept your own answer too. I will be glad to upvote it. *Cheers*

Comment: PhpStorm benefits from proper PHPDoc blocks, especially in cases where PhpStorm unable to figure out method's exact return type by using static analysis only. I suggest to check this link for more info about PHPDoc: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md

Comment: @Fred-ii- I posted the answer could you plz up vote it now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently in my DbConnect class my PHPDoc comments stated that I was returning 'database' when in fact I was returning a 'mysqli' datatype. This was what was causing the error. The simply fix to this problem was to change be PHPDoc annotation to 'mysqli' and the code completions started to work again.

Answer (score 1):

the `@return database connection handler` annotation is telling PhpStorm that you're returning a type 'database'.  You are actually returning a 'mysqli' object, so you should have the annotation be `@return mysqli the database connection handler`