# Error under PHPStrorm 8.0.3, Laravel Plugin 7.2 and IDE HELPER 2.0.3

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am receiving an error under [PHPStrorm 8.0.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), [Laravel Plugin 7.2](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin) and [IDE HELPER 2.0.3](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

I have followed all of the steps in the instructions.

1. Installed the IDE Helper with composer
2. Generated the ide helper file
3. Installed the Larvel Plugin
4. Enabled my plugin for my project.
5. Restarted PHPStorm.

In some files, such as routes.php, the plugin works as expected.

But in other files it does not work.

Any ideas on how I might be able to get this to work?

**routes.php working**

[image: route]

**CommandHandler.php not working**

[image: commandhandler]

Comment: I am pretty sure the solution is to add a doc item for the method, but don't remember exactly so I'm not posting an answer. This might be relevant however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582202/how-to-deal-with-method-not-found-in-class-warning-for-magically-implemented-m

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` an restart IDE -- may help.

Comment: Agreeing with @Ynhockey It should be a `/**` doc issue. Is the code working?

Comment: show us your doc comments pls

Comment: @pc-shooter What should the doc item look like and where would I find it.

Comment: @LazyOne I tried File | Invalidate and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Its above each method. just type `/**`  above the desired method and press enter. then phpstorm creates it with params and return (if any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you imported the class in your command handler with:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

However, the IDE helper generates the class as alias in the global namespace, so change it to:

```
use Storage;
```