# Why isn't my IDE auto-completing the findOrFail method?

Tags: laravel, lumen

So I've created a Message model:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setSortOrder($sortOrder)
    {
        $this->sort_order = $sortOrder;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And it seems to be working just fine - I've created some columns using migrations, loaded, and saved the model.

But my IDE (PHP Storm) doesn't seem to be recognizing some of the methods on the model - namely `findOrFail`.  It does autocomplete `findOrNew` though.

Wondering whether something in lumen is pointing to a more stripped-down version of the base model class.  But again the weird thing is that this method is working just fine when I run it - it's just the IDE that doesn't seem to be aware of it.

[image]

#### Update

Thanks @joseph-silber for the tip about the [Laravel plugin for PHPStorm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532).  I just found that and installed it.  I'm not seeing any settings immediately that would enable docblock generation in there.

[image]

In the notes for the Laravel plugin page, it mentions the "Laravel IDE Helper Generator".  I did a search for that and found this [Laravel plugin by Haehnchen](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin) which I installed.

This added the `ide-helper:models` option to my artisan command list as well as a few others.  I ran that and it did generate some methods in the docblock but not all of them.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent ORM Code Hinting in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439753/eloquent-orm-code-hinting-in-phpstorm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the model class doesn't have a [`findOrFail`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2ae928a3f0489f80f8b6892202506eea6ef8f725/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L151-L158) method.

It's only available on the builder, which gets called from the model's catch-all [`__call`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2ae928a3f0489f80f8b6892202506eea6ef8f725/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3480-L3482) method.

---

If you want PHP Storm to help you out there, try the [Laravel plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532) to generate the IDE classes.

Comment: I installed that one as well as another plugin that it referenced - still no luck - posted some detail as an update to my original question.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @kalenjordan - Yeah. Those plugins haven't been updated to 5.1 yet.

Comment: as a workaround, phpStorm has an option to **downgrade severity if __magic methods are present in class**. [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35347256/1296104)

Answer (score 2):

Use query() method and you have IDE autocomplete there `User::query()->findOrFail(...)` that is equivalent to `User::findOrFail(...)` but with autocomplete for Laravel methods in st-bnv