# PhpStorm not recognizing methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ide, phpstorm

So this has been asked several times but I'm yet to find an answer that works.

I'm using PhpStorm - 2016.3.2 and Laravel 5.4

[image]

I have tried using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper and also the Laravel plugin for PhpStorm.

I tried checking the option "Downgrade severity if_magic methods are present in class" - this didn't work.

The only thing I can do to solve this is to turn the warnings off completely for undefined methods, but turning features like this off defeat the point of using an IDE.

Has anyone found a way to solve this?

Sources:

https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/15

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/why-does-phpstorm-not-recognise-all-the-classes?page=1

[PhpStorm laravel 5 method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072929/phpstorm-laravel-5-method-not-found)

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: *"So this has been asked several times but I'm yet to find an answer that works."* Please share links to those questions -- I would like to see what they about and what they offer. Quite possibly they are about different things (compared to your *simple* case).

Comment: I have added some of the links of places Ive looked. Most say the same thing tbh

Comment: Thanks. The links you have provided more about cases where magic methods are used .. or about some function that returns some object that can be of many types. Your case here is NOT specific to Laravel -- you will see the same with ANY framework, even your own code/library when you will be passing any object instance in the same way.

Comment: You have **very simple and basic case here**: you are passing parameter to a function without specifying what that parameter is. Either use type hints that PHP natively supports (as `Ross Wilson` showed).. or use PHPDoc to do that (`@param` tag) -- https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html. Using inline PHPDoc with `@var` is not needed in this particular case -- the above 2 are much more suitable/correct ways; but it can be used in other/more complex cases.

Comment: Did one of the posts below answer your question, @Brad, or do you need further information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because PHPStorm doesn't know what that variable is meant to be (it has nothing to be with Laravel). As far as PHPStorm knows it's just a param for a method.

As @LazyOne suggested, you can type hint the variable e.g.

```
public function scopeIncomplete(Builder $query)
```

Then at the top of the class just add the following `use` statement

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

Alternatively, if you're using a OS X (I'm not sure of the shortcuts for Windows or Linux) you can move the caret in the `Builder` reference and then hit `alt enter` to import the class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

PHPDoc blocks can come in handy for this.

You can add this PHP comment just before the statement *return $query*, inside the function

```
/** @var $query \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder */
```

In this way PHPStorm will correctly recognize the method

Comment: 1) `/** @var [Type] [$variable] */` is a correct way 2) Why not simply use more appropriate solution -- type hint for actual parameter (since `$query` is passed to that function that way)?

Comment: absolutely for both 1 & 2, I wrote the first solution that came up in my mind. option two is the proper way :).