# 'phpstorm' in not recognized in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

In Laravel project 'phpstorm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
what should i do

Comment: Perhaps there's a clue here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830077/phpstorm-is-not-recognizing-methods-of-my-model-class-in-laravel-5-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPStorm is not recognizing methods of my Model class in Laravel 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830077/phpstorm-is-not-recognizing-methods-of-my-model-class-in-laravel-5-0)